# Why does my session var increment by 2?

Tags: php, session-variables

Why is +1 to the session qty actually adding 2 if i hit a php page and the session qty = 2 when i get to the print statement in the code below it prints 4  if i refresh again it prints 6, refresh again and its 8. Why is the code below incrementing by 2 not 1?

```
<?php
    $maxx=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($ix=0;$ix<$maxx;$ix++){
        $pidx=$_SESSION['cart'][$ix]['productid'];

        $_SESSION['cart'][$ix]['qty'] = $_SESSION['cart'][$ix]['qty']+1;

        print $_SESSION['cart'][$ix]['qty'];
}
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart'][$ix]['qty'] = $_SESSION['cart'][$ix]['qty']+1;` should be `$_SESSION['cart'][$ix]['qty']++;` for better understanding.

Comment: why don't you `var_dump` the whole `$_SESSION["card"]` variable to see what it contains?

Comment: Also, you can use a `foreach` loop for arrays. Take a look at the PHP manual about it.

Comment: If it is incrementing by two, the code is likely being run twice, either by faulty logic, or this often happens because a rewrite rule actually loads the script twice.  Check your web server logs.

Comment: You should post the whole code of that page.

Comment: @Michael ok i think it is a rewrite rule issue causing the script to run twice.  If this is the case how do i get around it?

Comment: A redirect might cause this as well. And on an unrelated note, while a `foreach()` could help in working with shorter variable names, the `for()` loop performs way better.